# Flask & Boto3 `ValueError: Required parameter name not set` on Accessing Resource

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask

Every time I run my app, it works until I send a request to the `/files` route, where I get a `ValueError: Required parameter name not set`. The error does not specify what `parameter` is not set.

```
from flask import (
    Flask, render_template, redirect, 
    url_for, g, session, flash, request
)
from flask_session import Session
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField
from datetime import datetime
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, DateTimeField, TextField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, Length
from flask_sqlalchemy  import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import (LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user,
                         login_required, logout_user, current_user)
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_s3 import FlaskS3
import boto3
from config import S3_BUCKET, S3_KEY, S3_SECRET

s3 = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    aws_access_key_id=S3_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=S3_SECRET
)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['FLASKS3_BUCKET_NAME'] = 'flaskprofileproject'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "ASNDASNDASONDSAOIDMAODNAS"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:////Users/michaelaronian/Desktop/FlaskProject/database.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

# Code removed for brevity's sake

@app.route('/files')
def files():
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(S3_BUCKET)
    summaries = my_bucket.objects.all()

    return render_template('files.html', my_bucket=my_bucket, files=summaries)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=4100)
```

The rest of my application runs fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have created a config.py which has my AWS credentials. That displays this                   import os

S3_BUCKET                 = os.environ.get("S3_BUCKET_NAME")
S3_KEY                    = os.environ.get("S3_ACCESS_KEY")
S3_SECRET                 = os.environ.get("S3_SECRET")

Comment: For those wondering, this code seems to be mostly taken from [this excellent Flask/S3 walkthrough](https://kishstats.com/python/2018/03/15/flask-amazon-s3-series.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boto3 allows 3 ways to set credentials, documented [here](http://Botos3%20allows%203%20ways%20to%20set%20credentials).

It looks like you are using the 3rd method, linked above, of **Method Parameters** here:

```
s3 = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    aws_access_key_id=S3_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=S3_SECRET
)
```

The problem is, you aren't using the `s3` variable (storing the boto3 client) to access your resource. This method creates a "low-level client", meant for very specific access to your S3 resources. So if that is your intention, [read the docs on the `Client` class here](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client).

Otherwise, you can have `Boto` read from environment variables, [like in this method here](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#environment-variables), and then go about accessing your resource as you are doing above.

You'll have to set the following environment variables, likely in your `~/.bash_profile` on localhost, so `boto3` knows how to connect to your AWS S3 Bucket. In your `~/.bash_profile`, add:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="The access key for your AWS account."
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="The secret key for your AWS account."
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="The session key for your AWS account."
# This is only needed when you are using temporary credentials, so you can probably ignore it!
```

After editing this file, save it, and run a `source ~/.bash_profile` to export your new env variables into your environment (*in the same shell that you're starting your server in)*, and start your server.